# Google maps snap to road for walking - Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have an iOS app that is using the Google Maps SDK. I track a user as they walk or run then use those coordinates to plot their course along the road using snap to roads.

I have found however the snap to roads uses the direction of the road to plot the course so when it comes to roundabouts the course follows this around even if the user was on the inside of the block.

Is there a way to use snap to roads (or directions) that allows for walking tracks and follows the shortest distance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap?hl=en), snap to road is not for walking...

> The snapToRoads method takes up to 100 GPS points collected along a route, and returns a similar set of data, with the points snapped to the most likely roads the **vehicle** was traveling along.

but well.. what you can do it to compare the points, and if the returned points are "some" distance faraway then the original point, you know that this points should be inside the block.

Comment: I read that. That's why I mentioned directions however the amount of points I am generating is way greater than the 8 allowed in direction requests. I am generating about 900 in each go and from those creating 100 evenly spaced then using those in the snap to roads. My concern with using directions is 8 may give wrong paths.